# Rushed publications based on flawed data

Tags: history-of-chemistry

In 2014 BICEP2 made a very controversial press release. It was rushed, given before any papers where published, because they feared they would be scooped by another similar experiment. In the end it turned out that their analysis of their data was flawed. It was particularly dramatic because if they had been correct it would have been a significant development.

Are there any similar cases in chemistry? Not necessary an identical situation, but a high profile result that was released in a hurry that later turned out to be incorrect.

Comment: You might want to try [Retraction Watch](http://retractionwatch.com/?s=chemistry).

Comment: It looks off-topic here, flagging for migration to Academia SE

Comment: The Schön affair comes to mind (a fraud on the part of J.H.Schön, but an honest mistake on the part of his coauthors).

Comment: Since it is only my personal opinion, that your question is not on topic here, I am not going to close it. (@Mithoron Please flag for migration **after** the question has been closed by the community.) I am absolutely uncertain about how on topic it is at [academia.se]. Please inform yourself about their policies. It could be also on topic on [hsm.se], same advice applies.

Comment: [Very similar version on HSM.](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/rushed-publications-based-on-flawed-data)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the publication of chemistry results, and not about the technical aspects of the science of chemistry itself.